# Android Virtual Device Manager interface shows part of its interface

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

AVD runs but shows me part of its interface only. I have no idea why. Here screenshot of my problem
https://www.dropbox.com/s/frhfn9c9ya1fso6/AVDproblem.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you running windows inside Virtual Machine?

It could also be caused by screen resolution.

Comment: No, Windows is main system.